# Can i use wget to download multiple files from linux terminal

Tags: linux, download, centos

Suppose i have a directory accessible via http e,g

`Http://www.abc.com/pdf/books`

Inside the folder i have many pdf files

Can i use something like

`wget http://www.abc.com/pdf/books/*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wget -r -l1 -A.pdf http://www.abc.com/pdf/books
```

Comment: This only works if `http://www.abc.com/pdf/books` leads to a page containing links to the PDF files.

Comment: That was implied: "Suppose i have a _directory accessible via http_". If web server does not have directory browsing enabled for a folder of images this method will fail, yes.

Answer (score 3):

from wget man page:

> ```
>    Wget can follow links in HTML and XHTML pages and create local versions of remote web sites, fully recreating the directory structure of the original site.  This is
>    sometimes referred to as ``recursive downloading.''  While doing that, Wget respects the Robot Exclusion Standard (/robots.txt).  Wget can be instructed to convert the
>    links in downloaded HTML files to the local files for offline viewing.
> ```

and

> ```
>    Recursive Retrieval Options
> ```

```
   -r
   --recursive
       Turn on recursive retrieving.

   -l depth
   --level=depth
       Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.  The default maximum depth is 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the webserver and the configuration of the server.   Strictly speaking the URL is not a directory path, so the `http://something/books/*` is meaningless.

However if the web server implements the path of `http://something/books` to be a index page listing all the books on the site, then you can play around with the [recursive option](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and spider options and wget will be happy to follow any links which is in the `http://something/books` index page.